# Fancyvrb watermark/footer at the end how to remove it?

Tags: fancyvrb

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Role specification for a user U$_{i}$]{{ \fbox{\begin{minipage}{17.6em} \VerbatimInput[fontsize=\relsize{-2.5},baselinestretch=1]{RoleUser.txt} \end{minipage}} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Role specification for $TA$]{{ \fbox{\begin{minipage}{19em} \VerbatimInput[fontsize=\relsize{-2.5},baselinestretch=1]{RoleTA.txt} \end{minipage}} }}%
    \caption{Role specification for U$_{i}$ and the $TA$.}%
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}
```

[image]

[File attached here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar3Q75XtPb-pg58494iO0sOSVTbs7w)

Comment: Please add a compilable example code.

Comment: The link to attached file shows "This item might not exist or is no longer available."